# jquery live on :after selector

Tags: jquery, css

How can I add a live event binding to :after selector? Here's what I tried without success:

css rules

```
div.k-tabstrip .k-link:after
{
    content: url("/icons/close.gif");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

js

```
$(document).on("click",".k-link:after", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Content added by `:after` and the `content` property does not become part of the DOM and is therefore not accessible by JavaScript.

Note that the content is not added to the DOM *at all*, so it doesn't become part of the element it was applied to, and it doesn't become a node in it's own right. It just sort of sits there on its own, unaware of the world around it.

Answer (score 2):

[James's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756203/398242) is 100% correct.

Since your `:after` content in this case is useless without javascript, you can use javascript to add the element in the first place:

```
$('.k-link').append('<img src="/icons/close.gif" class="after">');
$(document).on("click",".k-link .after", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

Of course, use more sensible, meaningful class names than `after`.

If the element does have a function outside of javascript (if the link/button should work with js disabled), and is not merely decoration, it should really be in your HTML to begin with. Likewise, anything that is **content** and not **presentation** should be part of your markup and not generated with CSS.